# Built-In Widgets in Kentico MVC?

Tags: kentico, kentico-mvc, kentico-12

In Kentico Portal Engine, you have a huge list of widgets (aka, web parts) to choose from. I could be wrong, but it seems like these cannot be used when content editors are working with the "Pages" tab for MVC-based websites (i.e., not Portal Engine, which uses Web Forms).

**Does Kentico have a suite of widgets that can be used with MVC?** Maybe it's just some setting or setup step that I'm missing so they become available? I would like to avoid building everything from scratch.

**Background**: I'm new to Kentico (I'm going through the training courses), so I may have some of these terms mixed up (e.g., I think widgets are configured web parts, but I'm not super sure). Using Kentico 12.

**Edit**: Since Zan RAKOTO asked, I am more curious in general, but as a starting point I'd be curious if there are blog widgets out of the box or via some marketplace (e.g., blog article listing, search, category filter, year/month filter, newsletter signup form, social icon links to share an article, author list, image, rich text, and so on).

Comment: The portal engine evolved for more than 13 years - at the beginning it did not had all the features too. We are working hard to provide more out of the box features and widgets for MVC too - but we cannot do everything at once, we have also limited resources and day has only 24hrs...:-)

Comment: Maybe it would be better to ask directly what kinds of widgets do you wish to have on MVC. Maybe someone within the community have that can guide you toward the solution.

Comment: @ZanRAKOTO I've updated the question with more details (the "Edit" near the bottom). Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kentico MVC installation does not have standard widgets. You need to create them yourself.

You can take a look at the kentico [marketplace](https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace). There you can find some standard widgets that can be installed. You can also take a look at the Dancing Goat example for some widgets that you can use.

Comment: there are few out of the box MVC widgets - like editable area, online form, images...not many, but there are more to come in the future.